# How to add class delay or remove class execute in behind add class div?

Tags: jquery

In slider includes three slides, When click on first slide, it adds class and  it clips (hides) and same with second and third slide.

HTML code

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slides">
        <div class="slide">1</div>
        <div class="slide">2</div>
        <div class="slide">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.slider-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 80px 40px; 
    text-align: center;
    background: #333;
    clip: rect(0 1060px 660px 0);
    -webkit-transition: linear .5s;
    transition: linear .5s;

}
.slide:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #404040;
    z-index: 3;
}
.slide:nth-child(2) {
    z-index: 2;
}
.slide:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #404040;
    z-index: 1;
}
.slide-clip {
    clip: rect(0 0 660px 0);
}
```

Jquery Code

```
$('.slide').click(function() {
  var $target = $(this).next();
  if ($target.length == 0)
    $target = $('.slide:first');

  $(this).delay(1000).addClass('slide-clip');
  $target.removeClass('slide-clip');
});
```

I expect that when second slide adds class and clips (hide) before that or in behind third slide, first slide unclip and same as third slide click, second slide unclip behind first slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) method only works with jQuery animation queue so it won't make any delay on [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass) method. To adding `class` after 1 second you can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) method.

```
setTimeout(() => $(this).addClass('slide-clip') , 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I used it but in console, found error that setTimeOut is not defind, can you improve your answer  to fix this problem please.

Comment: yes, problem is fixed but not any function execute on click. It stuck.

Comment: @Ramesh : oops fixed that as well... it's about the scope issue..... using arrow function it will fix

Comment: Ok, I have no deep knowledge about arrow function, can you help me about this issue. Thanks

Comment: @Ramesh :  `setTimeout(() => $(this).addClass('slide-clip') , 1000);`